# Multifile upload is not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the following form in which the user can select the files to upload. This part is okay, the multi-select is working:

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload">
          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">Fájlok feltöltése</button>
        </form>
```

And the following php which is used to upload the files:

```
     <?php
        $ID = uniqid();
        mkdir("temp/" . $ID);
        $target_dir = "temp/" ;
        $target_file = $target_dir . "/" . $ID . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $target = basename($target_file,".docx");
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if file already exists
       // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
        ?>
```

I can,t make the code working. I tried many different ways. I suppose that I need a foreach somewhere but where? What am I doing wrong?

update: If I paste upload.php: `die('<pre>'.print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"], true).'</pre>');` at the begging of the php I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => sablonTeszt20150805.docx
            [1] => sablonTeszt20150805 másolat.docx
            [2] => sablonTeszt20150805 másolat 2.docx
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
            [1] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
            [2] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpiu1FTX
            [1] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHm4xiV
            [2] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpjKZV72
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65647
            [1] => 65647
            [2] => 65647
        )

)
```

Comment: From the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php ..you should go through the comments

Comment: Yes I think I can find it somewhere, however I tried for a while and now I think that maybe it is easier if somebody help me.

Comment: paste the following at the top of `upload.php`: `die('<pre>'.print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"], true).'</pre>');` and upload 2 files. Paste the response in your original post.

Comment: Thanks. Now for clarification you have many places in your code referencing image uploading, yet you save the file as a docx. What file types are you allowing?

Comment: Only docx. It was working with single file upload. Only this line was different: <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload"> it was like this: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

Comment: on the finalized version are you going to store all uploaded files in a single directory? I'm assuming the mkdir() temp is for testing.

Comment: The mkdir() is because it is possible that more than one user will use the site at the same time. So it is better to keep their files in separated directories.

Comment: So actually I will store the files in one directory, yes.

Comment: @user2666249 If I'm right, then *temp* will be your master directory and in that directory you want to create several directories based on `$ID` for each user, right?

Comment: Yes that is the situation!

Comment: @user2666249 I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload multiple .docx files, this is what you can do. At every critical step I added comments to make you understand what's happening at each step.

**HTML**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload">
  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">Fájlok feltöltése</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $ID = uniqid();

        // file mode: 777
        // read, write and execute for everyone
        // you should change this file mode based on your requirement
        mkdir("temp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $ID, 0777, true);

        $target_dir = "temp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $ID ;

        // count the number of files uploaded
        $num_of_files = count($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        // loop through each file to upload
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_of_files; ++$i){
            $target_file = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
            $uploadOk = 1;

            // get the file extension
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // check if it's a .docx file
            if($ext == "docx"){

                // Check if file already exists
                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

                    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                } else {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                        echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded.";
                    } else {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }

                }

            }else{
                echo "only .docx files are allowed";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

**Sidenote:** In order to provide cross-platform compatibility, you should use PHP's `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to write path strings, e.g. `"..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."foo"`, because the way to do it on Windows would be `"..\foo"` while on everything else (Linux, UNIX, Mac OS X) it would be `"../foo"`.

Comment: Why do you "this this is what the OP is looking for"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is a key feature. The code below will validate each file in the fileToUpload[] array based on two criteria. Allowed extension and filename duplication. If the file passes validation it will be moved to the users directory.

Also, when multiple files are uploaded a single file validation error will not end processing. Validated files will be processed. This results in a better user experience.

The processing steps are broken down into 3 functions for ease of reading.

**HTML Form**

```
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload">
      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">Fájlok feltöltése</button>
    </form>
```

**PHP Form Handling**

```
<?php
IF (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // form submitted

 $ID = uniqid(); // future userid
 $dir = "temp". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $ID; // upload directory

 IF (empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
    echo("<p>No file(s) uploaded</p>");
 }ELSE{

  $files = Validate_Uploads($dir); // validate uploaded file(s)
  $response = Process_Files($dir, $files); // process uploaded files
  echo(Upload_Response($response));

 }

}
?>
```

**PHP Functions**

```
<?php
Function Validate_Uploads($dir) {

    // returns an array value for each file in $_FILES[]
    /*
        validates each file uploaded
        # is it a docx file
        # does it already exist
        # generates error message on failed validation for each file
    */

    $result = array();
    $fileexts = array('docx'); // allowed file extensions

    $filecnt = count($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    IF ($filecnt == 1) {
        // one file uploaded
        $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], '.'), 1)); // file ext.

        // validate file type
        IF (in_array($ext, $fileexts)) {
            $error = NULL;

            // Check if file already exists
            IF (file_exists($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) {
                $error = "The file (".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'].") already exists.<br />";
            }

        }ELSE{
            $error = "The file type of (".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'].") is not supported. (Only ".implode(", ",$fileexts).")<br />";
        }

        $result[] = array(
            'filename' => $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'],
            'tempfile' => $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
            'ext' => $ext,
            'error' => $error
        );

    }ELSE{

        // multiple files uploaded
        for ($i = 0; $i < $filecnt; ++$i) {
            $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i], '.'), 1)); // file ext.

            // validate file type
            IF (in_array($ext, $fileexts)) {
                $error = NULL;

                // Check if file already exists
                IF (file_exists($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i])) {
                    $error = "The file (".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i].") already exists.<br />";
                }

            }ELSE{
                $error = "The file type of (".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i].") is not supported. (Only ".implode(", ",$fileexts).")<br />";
            }

            $result[] = array(
                'filename' => $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i],
                'tempfile' => $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i],
                'ext' => $ext,
                'error' => $error
            );

        }

    }

    return $result;

}

Function Process_Files($dir, $files) {

    // returns a response (success/fail) message foreach file uploaded.
    $result = array();

    IF ( (!file_exists($dir)) && (!is_dir($dir)) ) {
        mkdir($dir);
    }

    Foreach($files as $key => $file) {

        IF (is_null($file['error'])) {

            IF (move_uploaded_file($file['tempfile'], $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file['filename'])) {
                $result[] = "The file ". $file['filename']. " has been uploaded.<br />";
            }ELSE{
                $result[] = "Sorry, ".$file['filename']." could not be uploaded.<br />";
            }

        }ELSE{
            $result[] = $file['error'];
        }

    }

    return $result;

}

Function Upload_Response($response) {

    // formats response msgs in a paragraph
    $result = "";

    foreach($response as $msg) {
        $result .= $msg;
    }

    return "<p>" . $result . "</p>";

}
?>
```