# Single file to Multiple files upload using PHP, MySQL, JS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, file

I have a script to upload single file to server, pass the value of destination and save every data in the database. I would like to change that script from single file to upload multiple files.
Script:
**upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?
if ($_SESSION['id'])
{
    $usr = $_SESSION['usr'];
    ?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var dest = _("cat").value;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "page/upload_verify.php?send=" + dest + "&usr=<? echo $usr ?>");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bites of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% has been uploaded... Wait...";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}


function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "File upload has been failed...";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "File upload has been cancelled...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Upload</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" value="Choose file"><br>
  <select id="cat" name="cat">
    <option value="movies">Movies</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="apps">Apps</option>
    <option value="other" selected="selected">Other</option>
    <option value="games">Games</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile(); return false;">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
else
{
    echo "<h2>You have no permission to view this file. Leave now!</h2>";
}
?>
```

and **upload_verify.php**

```
<?php
include ("../connect.php");
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

    $usr = $_GET['usr'];
    $dest = $_GET['send'];

$path = "download/$dest";

if($fileSize > 1073741824){
    die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
}
else
{
if(file_exists('test_uploads/' . $fileName)){
    die('File with the same name already exist.');
}
else{
    if ($fileSize > 1024 && $fileSize <= 1048576)
    {
        $new_FileSize = $fileSize / 1024;
        $new_FileSize = round($new_FileSize, 2);
        $bytes = "KB";
    }
    else if ($fileSize > 1048576)
    {
        $new_FileSize = $fileSize / 1024 / 1024;
        $new_FileSize = round($new_FileSize, 2);
        $bytes = "MB";
    }
    else
    {
        $bytes = "Bytes";
    }
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "File $fileName has been uploaded by $usr in: $dest";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (filename, size, bytes, type, date, bywho, cat, path) VALUES (
        '".$fileName."',
        '".$new_FileSize."',
        '".$bytes."',
        '".$fileType."',
        now(),
        '".$usr."',
        '".$dest."',
        '".$path."'
        )") or die("Something went wrong...");
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
}
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to change that script so I can upload multiple files.
I've changed

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" value="Choose file"><br>
```

for

```
<input multiple type="file" name="file1[]" id="file1" value="Choose file"><br>
```

so I can select multiple files and place them in array. Next I've change some part of **upload_verify.php** file so I can do the same action for every file in array.

Now it looks like this:

```
<?php
include ("../connect.php");
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

    $usr = $_GET['usr'];
    $dest = $_GET['send'];

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file1']['name']); $i++){
    $target_path = "../test_uploads/";
    $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file1']['name'][$i]));
    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded successfully <br />";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";
    }
}
?>
```

I know that script is not finished yet, but I'm trying to do it partially so I know where I've made a mistake. Now I have no idea what went wrong. Can I count for your help, please?
Thank you very much in advance for every help I can get.

Comment: An initial glance, the `count($_FILES['file1']['name'])` looks wrong, since the name is `file1[]` you'll want `count($_FILES['file1'])`

Comment: Check this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006454/multifile-upload-is-not-working/34009625#34009625

this is pretty much a copy paste working script I posted yesterday.

Comment: on the new files you updated.  you are calling to `$_FILES["file1"]["name"]` and other elements of the `$_FILES` elements which are not already existing.